# How do I create button with an icon in the center in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-button, material-components-android

I'm supposed to create a button with an icon in the center of the button next to the text like this:

[image]

This is the solution I came up with:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/tomato"
    app:cardCornerRadius="70dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add This To Cart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

but I think it's very hard coded. So, my question is: is there any better way to design it or some library used to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `MaterialButton`:

```
   <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
       app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
       app:iconPadding="0dp"
       app:iconGravity="textStart"
       app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.rounded50"
       ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.rounded50" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start using the [Material Components library](https://material.io/components?platform=android), which comes with a great number of pre-built modern components to prevent having to implement trivial things like this yourself.

Then you can use `MaterialButton` and set the icon attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:icon="@drawable/..." />
```

You can check out the specific [documentation](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#using-buttons) for information on styling etc.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your  ImageView and then
Write this line in the TextView

`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24`"

In your code .

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add This To Cart"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="25dp" 
androidd:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24/>
```

Comment: Oh. Didn't know I can do that. Thanks.